OSError: libmmal.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
I have a raspberry pi4 and i was trying to capture the camera output. Here's the code:

from picamera import PiCamera

camera = PiCamera()
camera.start_preview(alpha=192)

on interpreting this gives me following error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/Documents/codes/cam.py", line 1, in <module>
    from picamera import PiCamera
  File "/home/user/pyvenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/picamera/__init__.py", line 72, in <module>
    from picamera.exc import (
  File "/home/user/pyvenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/picamera/exc.py", line 41, in <module>
    import picamera.mmal as mmal
  File "/home/user/pyvenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/picamera/mmal.py", line 49, in <module>
    _lib = ct.CDLL('libmmal.so')
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/ctypes/__init__.py", line 376, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
OSError: libmmal.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I checked for this file from dpkg but it showed no results:
$ sudo ldconfig -p | grep "mmal"
$

I have updated the system from both apt and rpi-update but it didn't fix the issue.
How do I solve this issue?
System info:
$ uname -a
Linux raspberrypi 6.6.22-v8+ #1747 SMP PREEMPT Wed Mar 27 17:04:50 GMT 2024 aarch64 GNU/Linux


Sometimes, the installation might have been incomplete or corrupted. Reinstalling the library might help.

I assume that is Raspberry Pi OS Bookworm that you are using.
You should be using picamera2, picamera is out of date.
https://github.com/raspberrypi/picamera2/blob/main/examples/capture_jpeg.py
#!/usr/bin/python3

# Capture a JPEG while still running in the preview mode. When you
# capture to a file, the return value is the metadata for that image.

import time

from picamera2 import Picamera2, Preview

picam2 = Picamera2()

preview_config = picam2.create_preview_configuration(main={"size": (800, 600)})
picam2.configure(preview_config)

picam2.start_preview(Preview.QTGL)

picam2.start()
time.sleep(2)

metadata = picam2.capture_file("test.jpg")
print(metadata)

picam2.close()

